# Can't center a div with react and tailwindcss

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I can't seem to center a div the normal way with react and tailwind whatever I try I get this  [image]

Her is my code:

```
"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";

const LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen">
      <div className="flex-shrink-0 p-4">
        <Image
          src="/big-logo-black-ai.svg"
          alt="Logo"
          className="w-12 h-12"
          width={400}
          height={40}
        />
      </div>

      <div className=" flex justify-center items-center ">
        <div className="w-full max-w-md">
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Login</h1>
          <form>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <label
                htmlFor="email"
                className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
              >
                Email
              </label>
              <input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                className="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-md px-3 py-2 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-500"
                placeholder="you@example.com"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="w-full bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-md py-2 font-semibold hover:bg-blue-600"
              >
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

Please can somebody help me?
I have tried many other ways to center a div I have reconstructed the div many times but every time the div is locked to the left

Answer (score 2):

You can try add class w-full

```
"use client";
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";

const LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen w-full">
     ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you want to center the "div" horizontally only. You see this line of code :

```
const LoginPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen">
     ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

As this div is the parent div and it's width is not set to full screen width, it's children div would not be centered horizontally with respect to the screen size. So to solve this, just as the above person answered above, set the parent div to take full width of the screen :

```
const LoginPage = () => {
 return (
   <div className="flex w-full h-screen">
    ...
   </div>
 )
}
```

Hope this helped you!